# Transition between scenes is slow on first time

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I tried to move between GameScene to SettingsScene and is works perfect expect first time.
In first time the game is "stuck" for 1-3 seconds and presented the SettingsScene without the transition, after first time the transition and game works perfect.
The back (between SettingsScene to GameScene) works good also in first time.

The transition code between GameScene to SettingsScene

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        self.removeAllActions()
        // Get the location of the touch in this scene
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        // Check if the location of the touch is within the button's bounds
        //Play Button
        if PlayButton.contains(location) {
            bannerView.isHidden = true
            let newScene = PlayScene(size: (view?.bounds.size)!)
            newScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            let reveal = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0)
            self.view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: reveal)

            //Settings Button
        }else if SettingsButton.contains(location) {
            bannerView.isHidden = true
            settingsscene?.scaleMode = .resizeFill
            let reveal = SKTransition.push(with: SKTransitionDirection.down, duration: 0.7)
            self.view?.presentScene(settingsscene!, transition: reveal)
        }
    }
}
```

GameScene:

```
var settingsscene: SKScene?

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    //
    let size = self.size
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async {
        [weak self] () -> Void in
        self?.settingsscene = SettingsScene(size: (view.bounds.size))
    }
```

SettingsScene:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    //Settings Background
    settingsBackground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    settingsBackground.zPosition = -1

}

override init(size: CGSize) {

    super.init()
    //Settings Label
    settingsLabel.text = "Settings"
    settingsLabel.fontName = "AvenirNext-Bold"
    settingsLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    settingsLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    settingsLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    adjustLabelFontSizeToFitRect(labelNode: settingsLabel, rect: CGRect(x:self.frame.midX, y:self.frame.midY, width: 180, height: 110), center: true)
    settingsLabel.setScale(self.frame.width * 0.001)
    settingsLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.maxY - settingsLabel.frame.height)
    settingsLabel.zPosition = 1

    addChild(settingsLabel)
    /**** Labels ****/

    //Sounds Label
    soundsLabel.text = "Sounds"
    soundsLabel.fontName = "AvenirNext"
    soundsLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    adjustLabelFontSizeToFitRect(labelNode: soundsLabel, rect: CGRect(x:self.frame.midX, y:settingsLabel.position.y - 20, width:110, height: 70), center: true)
    soundsLabel.setScale(self.frame.width * 0.001)
    soundsLabel.zPosition = 1

    //Rate Label
    rateLabel.text = "Rate Game"
    rateLabel.fontName = "AvenirNext"
    rateLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    adjustLabelFontSizeToFitRect(labelNode: rateLabel, rect: CGRect(x:self.frame.midX, y:50, width:120, height: 110), center: true)
    rateLabel.setScale(frame.width * 0.001)
    rateLabel.zPosition = 1

    //Twitter Label (Follow me)
    twiterLabel.text = "Follow me"
    twiterLabel.fontName = "AvenirNext"
    twiterLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    adjustLabelFontSizeToFitRect(labelNode: twiterLabel, rect: CGRect(x:self.frame.midX, y:10, width:17, height: 110), center: true)
    twiterLabel.setScale(frame.width * 0.001)
    twiterLabel.zPosition = 1

    //iAP Label (Remove Ads)
    iapLabel.text = "Remove Ads"
    iapLabel.fontName = "AvenirNext"
    iapLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    adjustLabelFontSizeToFitRect(labelNode: iapLabel, rect: CGRect(x:self.frame.midX, y:70, width:40, height: 110), center: true)
    iapLabel.setScale(frame.width * 0.001)
    iapLabel.zPosition = 1

    //Restore iAP Label
    restoreLabel.text = "Restore Purchase"
    restoreLabel.fontName = "AvenirNext"
    restoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    adjustLabelFontSizeToFitRect(labelNode: restoreLabel, rect: CGRect(x:self.frame.midX, y:308, width:102, height: 110), center: true)
    restoreLabel.setScale(frame.width * 0.001)
    restoreLabel.zPosition = 1

    //About Label
    aboutLabel.text = "Restore Purchase"
    aboutLabel.fontName = "AvenirNext"
    aboutLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    adjustLabelFontSizeToFitRect(labelNode: aboutLabel, rect: CGRect(x:self.frame.midX, y:18, width:123, height: 312), center: true)
    aboutLabel.setScale(frame.width * 0.001)
    aboutLabel.zPosition = 1

    //Back Button
    backButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    backButton.zPosition = 1

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func SettingsSetup() {

    addChild(settingsBackground)
    addChild(myLabels)
    addChild(backButton)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch:AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in:self)

        //BackButton Action
        if backButton.contains(location) {
            let newScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
            newScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            let reveal = SKTransition.push(with: SKTransitionDirection.up, duration: 0.7)
            self.view?.presentScene(newScene!, transition: reveal)
        }

    }

}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It takes too long to load your scene the first time,  every time after that it is cached. Remove stuff from your didMove(view:) method and do it in the init

Comment: yup, just make sure you override all of the designated inits

Comment: @Knight0fDragon it's crash my app (I updated the code)

Comment: I am not seeing any update

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Check now

Comment: ughhh, never use view.bounds.size for your scenes

Comment: this code cant work, how are nodes like `settingsLabel` getting defined

Comment: It's define in Class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124650/discussion-between-avi-rok-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: Still no solution

Comment: I found out what I did,  I create the scene on a background thread, and when it is complete, I present it

Comment: I updated the code in question (the touchesBegen and GameScene) I did it ok? my app crash when I press settings button